# Short story collection identification

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I suspect that I may be conflating a couple of different books that I've read, but I'm looking for a short story collection that I read in the late 1970's, early 1980's.

Items that I remember:

- Cover was..purple? With two or three triangle shapes on it, slightly overlapping (They correlate to one of the stories)
- I *think* the title is similar to [Year's Best Science Fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Year%27s_Best_Science_Fiction) or along the lines of "Best of" or similar (I have been through all the Years Best covers on the wiki site)
- One short story that I definitely remember being in the book is [*Rain Rain Go Away*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain,_Rain,_Go_Away_(short_story)) by Asimov, but I've been through all the related books and [covers at the ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?68264). (This may be conflated, but I really remember it being in the book)
- The story with the triangle shaped creatures, they may have been two dimensional? IIRC they were either observing or being observed? They may have been purple while the cover was a different color, but purple was involved.

It was definitely in English, cover art that I remember was typical for the time, possibly slightly more dated (So similar to 1960's early 1970's cover art/fonts), paperback version.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7f/Fantastic_universe_195909.jpg ?

Comment: @Mithrandir I saw that cover but have not looked at the stories in it. The cover I remember was more abstract, almost like a microscope slide kind of view?

Comment: The only Year's Best series that goes that far back that I am aware of is the one by Judith Merril.  I checked the volumes for 1958, 59, and 60, and this story was not in them.  IMHO it's unlikely this story would be in a "best of" collection. None of the 3 collections have purple triangles on the editions I have.

Answer (score 3):

''Rain Rain Go Away'' appears [almost solely](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68264) in collections organized by Asimov himself. It's *possible* you mean The Complete Stories 2, but I don't think so from the description of [the cover](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?257914)? It's unlikely to be *Year's Best* simply because they started long after he wrote Rain Rain, but *The Science Fiction Hall of Fame* seems like a more likely hit but I can't find it appearing in any of those volumes.